# How to upload the image using Google Api Explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am using google endpoints and proto-datastore. I have a User entity which contains an image field which is of type BlobProperty. In the Google Api explorer, for input it provides a text box like other fields, how do i input the image in this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so its possible that you directly browse the image in the api explorer field. However you can use the BlobStore property to upload the image with the help of the form, After that you can put the reference for that Image in your api explorer field value. Refer some documents which gives you an idea of how to upload the image and Cloud Endpoints [1][2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/